# Dica de como transformar laços em função recursiva

Tags: php, recursão

Esse programa faz o teste de aptidão profissional baseado na logica de relações fuzzy. 
Tenho que transformar esses laços em uma função recursiva, pesquisei e até entendi como como uma função recursiva deve ser implementada, porém não consegui mentalizar uma forma de usar esses laços em uma. A função recursiva invoca ela mesmo como um laço de repetição até que uma condição de parada seja satisfeita. Como eu poderia transformar esses laços em uma função recursiva?

```
$aptidoes = array (
array ("aptidao_id" => "3","cod" => "ap1", "aptidao" => "Nível de Raciocínio Lógico?"),
array ("aptidao_id" => "4","cod" => "ap2", "aptidao" => "Gosta de Cálculos?"),
array ("aptidao_id" => "5","cod" => "ap3", "aptidao" => "Nível de Curiosidade?")
);

$casos = array (
array ("caso_id" => "35","nome" => "KELLY", "ap1" => "0.1", "ap2" => "0.1", "ap3" => "0.1")
);

$profissoes = array (
array ("profissao_id" => "1","profissao" => "Cientista da Computação", "ap1" => "1", "ap2" => "0.9", "ap3" => "0.9"),
array ("profissao_id" => "2","profissao" => "Psicologo", "ap1" => "0.5", "ap2" => "0", "ap3" => "0.6"),
array ("profissao_id" => "3","profissao" => "Professor de Humanas", "ap1" => "0.4", "ap2" => "0", "ap3" => "0.6")
);


//Pega repete a analise somente para o caso corrente, ou seja 1.
for ($p=0; $p < 1; $p++) { 
//Inicializa o arrey.
$_max = array();
//Pega todas as profissoes registradas no banco para análise.
for ($d = 0; $d < count($profissoes); $d++) {
    //Inicializa o arrey.
    $_min = array();
    //Pega todos as aptidões registrados no banco para análise.
    for ($i=1; $i < count($aptidoes)+1; $i++) { 
        //Cria um array com as relações (aptidão x profissao) e (aptidão x casos), e gera o valor mínimo de cada uma.
        array_push($_min, min($profissoes[$d]['ap'.$i],$casos[$p]['ap'.$i]));       
    }
//Recebe o valor mínimo da relação, para cada profissão.
$valor = max($_min);
//Gera um array com o valor máximo, da relação dos mínimos.
array_push($_max, $valor.' - '.$profissoes[$d]['profissao']);

  };
};

//Trás o resultado e a porcentagem de precisão.
echo '<h3><b>'.explode ("-", max($_max))[1].'</b> com precisão de '.(explode ("-", max($_max))[0] * 100).'%</h3>';
```

Comment: `teste de aptidão profissional baseado na logica fuzzy` http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/852/286/9ac.jpg

Comment: Não devo estar conseguindo explicar direito. Me ajudem. Pfv

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa entender [a estrutura do laço em PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php). Resumidamente, você tem:

```
for (a; b; c)
    d;
```

Onde:

- **a**: é uma expressão que é executada somente uma vez, antes do laço começar;
- **b**: é uma condição executada antes de cada passo do laço. Se for verdadeira o laço continua, caso contrário o laço para;
- **c**: é uma expressão que é executada ao final de cada passo;
- **d**: é uma expressão que é executada para cada passo do laço.

Portanto, o `for` acima é equivalente a este `while`:

```
a;
while(b) {
    d;
    c;
}
```

Como transformar isso em um algoritmo recursivo? A recursão consiste em um método chamar a si próprio, logo você precisa do seguinte:

```
function recursiva(parametrosOriginais) {
    if (b) return;
    else {
        d;
        c;
        return recursiva(parametrosAlterados);
    }
}

a;
recursiva(parametros);
```

Note que tanto no laço com `while` quanto na `recursão`, as expressões `c` e `d` podem ser combinadas em uma só. Mas o mais importante: na recursão, a execução dentro do `else` modificará os parâmetros que serão passados para a próxima chamada. Em todos os casos, `b` é a condição de parada. Ao ser atingida, o algoritmo para e você tem um resultado.

Segue um exempo de fatorial, iterativo e depois recursivo, em PHP.

Iterativo com `for`:

```
$param = 4; // pode ser qualquer outro número
$resultado = 1;
for ($i = $param; $i > 0; i--) {
    $resultado *= $i;
}
```

Iterativo com `while`:

```
$param = 4; // pode ser qualquer outro número
$resultado = 1;
$i = $param
while ($i > 0) {
    $resultado *= $i;
    $i--;
}
```

E finalmente, recursivo:

```
function fatorial($numero) {
    if ($numero == 1) return 1;
    else {
        $proximo = $numero - 1;
        return $numero * fatorial(proximo);
    }
}

$param = 4;
$resultado = fatorial($param);
```

Tente perceber o padrão, e poderá transformar praticamente qualquer algoritmo iterativo em uma versão recursiva (o inverso nem sempre é verdadeiro). Note que a função recursiva pode receber mais de um parâmetro se necessário.

Isso vale para dezenas de outras linguagens, desde C até Javascript.

Comment: Renan. Muito obrigado. Me ajudou muito essa sua explicação.